# R package in C depending on another R package

Tags: c, r

I am coding an R package in which I want to minimize some functions. As I am not happy with optimization functions of optim.c which are directly accessible, I want to use a package for my optimizations (rnlopt, optimx)...
My problem is how can I tell to R that my package depends on the other one (which is also a contributed package)? How can I compile and install my package in this case.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The answer to "how can I tell to R that my package depends on the other one" is you add `Depends: OtherPackage` to `DESCRIPTION`.

However, if you want to just re-use some C code, you can't really, unless the package has explicitly made an API available to use use with `LinkingTo` -- see R-ext 5.8: http://r.research.att.com/man/R-exts.html#Linking-to-other-packages
There are both legal and technical reasons for this.